# loop to get closest object to input value

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, compare

I have this Martian class:

```
public abstract class Martian implements Cloneable {
int id;

public Martian(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if( o != null);
    return this.getId() == ((Martian)o).getId();    
}
public abstract void speak();

public String toString(){
    return "Martian" + getId(); 
}       
}
```

and a MartianManager class:

```
public class MartianManager {
private ArrayList<Martian> martians;
private ArrayList<Martian> teleporters;

public void addMartian(Martian m) {
    martians.add(m);
    if(m instanceof GreenMartian)
        teleporters.add(m);
}
//public Object clone() {

public Martian getMartianClosestToID(int id) {

}
public void groupSpeak() {
    for(Martian m : martians) {
        m.speak();
    }
}
public void groupTeleport(String dest) {
    for (Martian m : martians){
        if (m instanceof GreenMartian)
            ((GreenMartian) m).teleport(dest);
    }   
}
//public obliterateTeleporters() 

//removeMartian(int id)
}
```

In the `MartianManager` class I have a method `getMartianClosestToId()` which returns the martian with the id closest to the input id. My question basically is what would be the simplest logic to use in a loop to do this, or is their an easier way to do it such as `compareTo` which I don't know if compare would even work in a situation like this.

Comment: As much as I'd like to help you, I strongly oppose cloning Martians.

Comment: Don't use the clone() method in Java. It is outdated. There are many flaws with it.

Comment: @gparyani It's not outdated. Just that it is not recommended to use it.

Comment: @RohitJain Take a look at [this bug report](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4220218) from the days of Java 1.2. In it, they specifically say that it is outdated.

Comment: How do you calculate the distance? Are there coordinates? Euclidian- or Manhatten-distance?

Comment: Say, if you have two Martians with ID 9 and 15 respectively, and someone calls `getMartianClosestToId(12)`, which one would you return? The one with ID 9, or the one with ID 15?

Comment: The logic is like this. Set the first `Martian` as the closest while storing the distance. Iterate through the rest. If the distance is smaller, replace the closest with that one.

Comment: Line 14 of your first code sample says `if(o != null);`.This should say `if(o == null) return false;`.

Comment: @RohitJain Effective Java (2nd ed.) Item 11 has a very misleading title of "Override Clone Judiciously" - reading the article, he's really saying "Here's why you shouldn't override clone". He closes with "Because of it's many shortcomings, some expert programmers simply choose to never invoke [clone] except, perhaps, to copy arrays." He highly recommends using copy constructors or copy factories instead.

Comment: @corsiKa. I know all that. I've also read that topic. I just assumed by outdated he meant deprecated. My Bad :(

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the simplest, but in a lot of cases it will be the fastest.

If you're willing to keep your list of martians always sorted by id (which is easy to do if you aren't adding martians very often, you can just sort when you add them), you can do this:

```
Comparator<Martian> compareById = new Comparator<Martian>() {
    public int compare(Martian a, Martian b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.getId(), b.getId());
    }
}
```

Then you can use a binary search on your list to find the spot where it would go in the list if it were to be inserted.

```
int location = Collections.binarySearch(martians, idToGetClosestTo, compareById);
```

Now at this point, you're going to have where it should go, and you'll have one of five options:

1. the location has the id you're looking for. If so, return martians.get(location);
2. the location provided wasn't in the list, meaning you're looking for something lower than the lowest, or higher than the highest.
   2.a. lower than the lowest: return the lowest, martians.get(0);
   2.b. higher than the highest: return the highest, martians.get(martians.length()-1);
3. the location is higher than the id you're looking for. (it won't be lower, otherwise you would have been given a result 1 lower than what you did!) So look at martians.get(location) and martian.get(location - 1) and see which one you're closest to and return the appropriate one.

This has an expensive upfront cost (sorting) but after you have it sorted, you can use binary search which is very cheap to find the closest martian very fast every time.

If you're going to be adding very often, then I recommend adding the new martians to the end and flagging your collection as unsorted, then only sorting when you're about to find one.

```
public Martian getMartianClosestToID(int id) {
    if(!martiansAreSorted) Collections.sort(martians,compareById);
    int loc = Collections.binarySearch(martians,id,compareById);
    if(loc >= 0) return martians.get(loc); // found exact match
    // we know loc is negative because it wasn't found - read the docs
    loc = -loc;
    if(loc == 0) return martians.get(0);
    if(loc == martians.size()) return martians.get(loc - 1);
    Martian high = martians.get(loc);
    Martian low = martians.get(loc - 1);

    int highid = high.getId();
    int lowid = low.getId();

    int highdiff = Math.abs(id - highid);
    int lowdiff = Math.abs(id - lowid);

    if(highdiff < lowdiff) return high;
    return low;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ought to work.

Whether this is exactly what you want depends on some assumptions.  Are the IDs unique?  Can a Martian be closest to itself?  What if there are two equally close Martians?  Or no other Martians?  I've assumed that the 'id' argument may be one of the IDs in the collection - and that you don't want that one.

But the biggest question is: what does 'closest' mean?  The concept of 'closeness' doesn't usually apply to IDs.

```
public Martian getMartianClosestToId(int id) {
    Martian closest = null;
    int leastDist = -1;
    for(Martian m : martians) {
        int mId = m.getId();
        if(mId == id)
             continue; // Skip the Martian with the same id.
        int d = Math.abs(mId - id);
        if(leastDist == -1 || d < leastDist) {
            leastDist = d;
            closest = m;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

I haven't compiled/tested this - you may need to fix typos/errors.

Comment: There were indeed some typos - just fixed them.

Comment: Note that this will return null if there are no Martians in the list, or only one Martian which has the same ID passed to the method.

Comment: Note that all of these solutions here (I think) may exhibit problems if some of the IDs are very small/large numbers.  (For example: two Martians - one has an ID of Integer.MIN_VALUE, the other Integer.MAX_VALUE.)

Answer (score 0):

This I think is simpler than the other answers so far (OP requested the "simplest logic"):

```
public Martian getMartianClosestToID(int id)
{
    if (martians == null || martians.isEmpty())
        return null;

    Martian result = martians.get(0);

    for (Martian m : martians)
        if (Math.abs(id - m.getId()) < Math.abs(id - result.getId()))
            result = m;

    return result
}
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if there aren't any Martians in the list.